# Unable to load Rails code in Javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

There is my part of code :

```
    $("table#table_field_type_users > tbody").append(`
<tr id='<%= @field_type_user.id%>' class='fields_type_user'>
  <td><input type='text' name='name_field_type_users' value='<%= j @field_type_user.name %>' class='form-control' id='name_field_type_user'/></td>
  <td><button type='button' name='delete_field_type_users' class='btn btn-danger' id='delete_field_type_users'>-</button></td>
</tr>
`);
```

But when JQuery append the following to the page, it render in plain text :

```
<tr id="<%= @field_type_user.id%>" class="fields_type_user">
  <td><input name="name_field_type_users" value="<%= j @field_type_user.name %>" class="form-control" id="name_field_type_user" type="text"></td>
  <td><button type="button" name="delete_field_type_users" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete_field_type_users">-</button></td>
</tr>
```

EDIT :

The first part of code is the part of an file called create.js that is rendered when the method created successfull... It seems it worked very well before the upgrade to Rails 5 ...

There is the process :

1. User press a button on page that make a Ajax call to the Create method.
2. The create method do the job and render with :

   format.js

Comment: and this is in a `.js.erb`?

Comment: No, this is an .js file EDIT : Thanks you it's work very well !! Stupid Am I !

Comment: then you cannot execute rails code :)

Comment: Yes ! Thank you ! :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$("table#table_field_type_users > tbody").append("
    <tr id='<%= @field_type_user.id%>' class='fields_type_user'>
        <td><input type='text' name='name_field_type_users' value='<%=@field_type_user.name %>' class='form-control' id='name_field_type_user'/></td>
        <td><button type='button' name='delete_field_type_users' class='btn btn-danger' id='delete_field_type_users'>-</button></td>
    </tr>");
```